# Using ticks 'major' with Chart.js is overlapping with an unknown text

Tags: chart.js

Using the following ticks config with Chart.js is overlapping with an unknown text only when the xAxes results are less than 7.

```
major: {
    enabled: true
}
```

Here is my code:

```
options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: 'time',
          distribution: 'series',
          display: true,

          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: false,
            autoSkip: true,
            maxTicksLimit: 10,
            maxRotation: 0,
            responsive: true,
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
            major: {
              enabled: true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The issue is bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess the cause of your problem without seeing more of your code. In below runnable code snippet I use the same options as you and it works just fine.

Please make sure to use the most recent stable version of Chart.js (currently [v2.9.3](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.3)) and check if this solves your problem.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'things',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
      data: [
        { t: new Date("05/01/2020"), y: 2 },
        { t: new Date("05/02/2020"), y: 0 },
        { t: new Date("05/03/2020"), y: 1 },
        { t: new Date("05/04/2020"), y: 7 },
        { t: new Date("05/05/2020"), y: 6 },
        { t: new Date("05/06/2020"), y: 4 }
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        distribution: 'series',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false,
          autoSkip: true,
          maxTicksLimit: 10,
          maxRotation: 0,
          responsive: true,
          legend: {
            display: false,
          },
          major: {
            enabled: true
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="90"></canvas>
```